# Name error name yes is not defined in pycharm

Tags: python

help
playing = input("Do you want to play? ")

```
if playing != "yes":
quit()
#when i run it says name yes is not defined
```

Comment: It's 2021, you don't wan't to expose yourself to Python 2. The currently recommended and supported version of the language is Python 3.

Comment: @S4nt4g017 Out of interest - how did you end up with Python 2? Do you use the new macOS with only it installed out of the box? Perhaps PyCharm can warn in such cases and suggest installing Python 3.